# How to set the SweelAlert2 Icons to aria-hidden="true"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

I use the latest SweetAlert2. For some [WCAG adjustments](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-hidden%3Dtrue_on_an_icon_font_that_AT_should_ignore) I have to set all icons to aria-hidden = "true". I have not found a suitable swal2 parameter for this.

With the parameter **onOpen:** and the corresponding function **setAriaIconsSwal()** I created a workaround. But it is a workaround with the unsightly setTimeOut. How can I do better?

```js
  function showSwalWcag() {
    Swal.fire({
      title: "WCAG Icon",
      text: "Text",
      icon: "error",
      onOpen: setAriaIconsSwal(),
      confirmButtonColor: "red",
      confirmButtonText: "OK"
    });
  }
  
   function showSwal() {
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Original Icon",
      text: "Text",
      icon: "error",
      confirmButtonColor: "red",
      confirmButtonText: "OK"
    });
  }
  
  function setAriaIconsSwal() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".swal2-icon").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
    }, 250);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="showSwalWcag();">click me (Edited swal)</button>
<button onclick="showSwal();">click me (Original swal)</button>
```

Comment: This is about the best you can get as annoyingly the Sweet Alert library only provides an `onOpen` event, which fires when the trigger is clicked and before the notification is actually displayed. It would be worth raising a change request for them to add another event which fires once the notification display animation has finished.

Comment: Following on from that, it has [already been requested](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/286), although it was over 5 years ago so I'm going to guess they don't care about implementing it.